# When to open and when to close the mysql connection while using Java servlets?

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc

Is it ok to open a connection in the `init` method and close it in the `destroy` method? Also what's the best way to open a connection to a mysql database. Currently I'm using this:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + ipaddress + "?user=" + user + "&password=" + pass);
```

But I read somewhere that this is inefficient and I should use connection pool. How to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would strongly suggest using a connection pool, either explicitly (such as [c3p0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/)) or one provided by your servlet container.

Open your database connection when you need it, then close it as soon as you can - the connection pool will take care of the real network connection.

Unless you do this, you'll end up with one connection for your whole application - which means you can only process one query at a time, and all your code needs to synchronize around database queries. Surely you want multiple entirely-independent queries to be able to execute simultaneously? You can't do this with a single connection.

As for the best way of opening a connection having configured an appropriate connection pool - you may well still end up using `DriverManager.getConnection()`, but specifying the connection pool instead of mysql directly.